# Extract Dump Files Files Names

Tags: linux, scripting, oracle-database

I'm trying to automate a database refresh but, now I'm stuck at a part trying to extract the dump files filename to use it with the IMPDP command.

The thing is that we use this parameter doing the export:

dumpfile=dbname_env_date_%u.dmp and a 16-degree parallelism, which creates 16 files like this:

```
dbname_env_date_01.dmp
dbname_env_date_02.dmp
.
.
.
dbname_env_date_16.dmp
```

What I'm trying to do is to just extract this "dbname_env_date", so I can use that parameter when importing into another env database.

What I've got so far is this:

```
dump_filename=$(ls -tr *.dmp | tail -1)
```

which gives me something like this:

```
dbname_env_date_16.dmp
```

and I want it to use later like this:

```
imdp \' / as sysdba \' dumpfile=${dump_filename}_u%.dmp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use tail, you know that you get all 16 files.

```
dump_filename=$(ls -t *_01.dmp | head -n 1)
dump_filename=${dump_filename%_01.dmp}
dump_filename="$dump_filename.dmp"
```

The first line will get the name of the newest file `*_01.dmp`, the second line will remove the `_01.dmp` from the name. The third line appends `.dmp`.

You can also use this:

```
dump_filename=$(ls -t *_01.dmp | head -n 1 | sed -e 's/_01\.dmp/.dmp/')
```

Comment: Hi, this actually does what I wanted, regarding the tail I use it because I want the latest dump files on the directory, sometimes no one cares to clean dump files that were already used. On the other hand, how can I do to preserve the ".dmp": to look like this "dbname_env_date.dmp". And is it possible to do it in one line piping the output or something like xargs?. Thank you very much for your help, I'm not very familiar with editing (Awk, Sed, Tr).

Comment: This will get you the newest file. Reversing the sorting and using the first line is in theory faster, because you don't need to read the whole output, but in practice the difference will not be noticeable. It is almost always possible to do it in one line, but is it worth the reduced readability?

Comment: Well, at least for me looks a lot better all in one line, at least in this case where the line seems pretty easy to read. Thank you very much for you help, I completetly forgot that sed can do that. Thank you Sir. I appreciate you help.

Comment: If the this answered your question, you can accept the answer.